# ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:CoffeeDB;create=true

Tags: jdbc

I have spent quite some time reading previous posts, but none of them seem to help me. I'm trying to run a simple Java app from NetBeans, here the simplest code:

```
final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:CoffeeDB;create=true";         
try
  {
     // Create a connection to the database.
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

     // If the DB already exists, drop the tables.
     dropTables(conn);

     // Build the Coffee table.
     buildCoffeeTable(conn);

     // Close the connection.
     conn.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
  }
```

---

Usually is the environmental variables causing trouble, but I have checked that and they seem to be set up correctly:

CLASSPATH:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\lib\derby.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\lib\derbytools.jar;

DERBY_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db

PATH:   (only the part concerning jdbc )
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\bin

I already created a table using ij from the command prompt and it worked, is when I try to run it through Netbeans when I get this error. Something interesting though, is when I run the sysinfo from the command prompt, it comes up like this:

------------------ Java Information ------------------

Java Version:    1.7.0_17

Java Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Java home:       C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Java classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\lib\derby.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db\lib\derbytools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db/lib/derby.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db/lib/derbynet.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db/lib/derbyclient.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\db/lib/derbytools.jar

OS name:         Windows Vista

OS architecture: amd64

OS version:      6.0

---> As you can see, somehow more information is added to the previous classpath, and the derbytools.jar and derby.jar appear twice?? combined with inverted slashes??

When debugging through NetBeans, the exception comes from this line in the DriverManager.java file:

```
    Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);     <--------------- here
    if (con != null) {
          // Success!
          println("getConnection returning " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
          return (con);
    }
```

the url is correct: jdbc:derby:CoffeeDB;create=true    but the connection comes back null and throws the SQLexception.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message *"No suitable driver found for ..."* means that none of the loaded JDBC drivers accepted the URL. This makes it very likely that the JDBC driver simply isn't included in the classpath of the application

The environment variable `CLASSPATH` is almost always ignored when a java application is run from an IDE, and always if run from an executable jar. Make sure that the build-path in the IDE actually contains derby.jar, or if it is an executable jar, that it is listed in the `META-INF/manifest.mf` in the `Class-Path` attribute.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! You were right! The classpath was not being even considerer when running from the IDE, I modified the build-path (Menu - Run - Set Project Configuration) and added the library derby.jar and it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can right click the project and do the following steps...Build -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar... now you have to specify the path to the *.jar file. 
simple example https://github.com/mraab89/Tutorial_Java_Database_Connectivity_JDBC